# Remove Byte Order Mark from a File.ReadAllBytes (byte[])

Tags: c#, byte-order-mark

I have an HTTPHandler that is reading in a set of CSS files and combining them and then GZipping them.  However, some of the CSS files contain a Byte Order Mark (due to a bug in TFS 2005 auto merge) and in FireFox the BOM is being read as part of the actual content so it's screwing up my class names etc.  How can I strip out the BOM characters?  Is there an easy way to do this without manually going through the byte array looking for "ï»¿"?

Comment: Is the BOM appearing in the actual text itself, or just at the very start? I'd be surprised to see it anywhere other than at the start of the data - in which case simply ignoring the first 3 bytes (assuming UTF-8) should do the trick.

Comment: FWIW, you could open the files in [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) and save them without the Byte Order Mark. It's what I had to do in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291455/xml-data-at-root-level-is-invalid).

Comment: I wrote the [following post](http://andrewmatthewthompson.blogspot.com/2011/02/byte-order-mark-found-using-net.html) after coming across this issue. Essentially instead of reading in the raw bytes of the file's contents using the BinaryReader class, I use the StreamReader class with a specific constructor which automatically removes the byte order mark character from the textual data I am trying to retrieve.

Answer (score 8):

Expanding on [Jon's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288111/remove-byte-order-mark-from-a-file-readallbytes-byte#comment21871755_288111) with a sample.

```
var name = GetFileName();
var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(name);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(name, bytes.Skip(3).ToArray());
```

Comment: Quote OP: *However, some of the CSS files contain a Byte Order Mark*. .. ** some ** .. so the code above doesn't check if there's a BOM, before it skips it...

Comment: But UTF-32 has a 4-byte BOM. In this case you have to skip 4

Answer (score 6):

Expanding JaredPar sample to recurse over sub-directories:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
namespace BomRemover
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Remove UTF-8 BOM (EF BB BF) of all *.php files in current & sub-directories.
    /// </summary>
    class Program
    {
        private static void removeBoms(string filePattern, string directory)
        {
            foreach (string filename in Directory.GetFiles(directory, file  Pattern))
            {
                var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
                if(bytes.Length > 2 && bytes[0] == 0xEF && bytes[1] == 0xBB && bytes[2] == 0xBF)
                {
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, bytes.Skip(3).ToArray()); 
                }
            }
            foreach (string subDirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(directory))
            {
                removeBoms(filePattern, subDirectory);
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filePattern = "*.php";
            string startDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            removeBoms(filePattern, startDirectory);            
        }       
    }
}
```

I had need that C# piece of code after discovering that the UTF-8 BOM corrupts file when you try to do a basic PHP download file.

Answer (score 3):

```
var text = File.ReadAllText(args.SourceFileName);
var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(args.DestFileName, args.Append, new UTF8Encoding(false));
streamWriter.Write(text);
streamWriter.Close();
```

Comment: Looking at this code, ideally it should work. But, I am surprised that it is saving file in ANSI format.

Comment: `new UTF8Encoding(false)` the parameter indicates whether to add the BOM or not.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, assuming UTF-8 to ASCII.

```
File.WriteAllText(filename, File.ReadAllText(filename, Encoding.UTF8), Encoding.ASCII);
```

Answer (score 0):

For larger file, use the following code; memory efficient!

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path: @"<Input_file_full_path_with_byte_order_mark>", 
                    detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: true);

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path: @"<Output_file_without_byte_order_mark>", 
                    append: false, 
                    encoding: new UnicodeEncoding(bigEndian: false, byteOrderMark: false));

var lineNumber = 0;
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    sw.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
    lineNumber += 1;
    if (lineNumber % 100000 == 0)
        Console.Write("\rLine# " + lineNumber.ToString("000000000000"));
}

sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
```